# Necessity of finiteness of a finitely additive $\mu$, continuous from above at $\emptyset$, in concluding that it's $\sigma$-additive

Tags: measure-theory

In the Measure Theory class, we proved that for a finitely additive function $\mu$ on an algebra $(X, \mathscr A)$, we have the following implications:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \text{$\mu$ is finite and continuous from above at $\emptyset$}\\
  \Downarrow\\
  \text{$\mu$ is continuous from below}\\
  \Downarrow\\
  \text{$\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive.}
 \end{gathered}
$$

**Question:** I was thinking if I could weaken "$\mu$ is finite" to "$\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite" (in the first statement), but couldn't get through a proof. Neither could I find any example showing the necessity of $\mu$ being finite with the limited knowledge I currently have. Can someone help?

---

We say that $\mu$ is continuous from above at $A\in\mathscr A$ iff for any $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq\cdots$ in $\mathscr A$ with $A = \cap_i A_i$ such that some $\mu(A_i) < +\infty$, we have that $\mu(A) = \lim_i \mu(A_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counter example.
Consider the counting measure $\mu$ on the nonnegative integers $\mathbb{N}$.
The measure $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Let $(A_n)$ be the sequence of sets defined for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by
\begin{equation*}
A_n = \{k\in\mathbb{N}:k\geq n\}.
\end{equation*}
This sequence is decreasing.
For each $n$ we have $\mu(A_n) = \infty$,
but $\bigcap_{n}A_n = \varnothing$,
so
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)
=
\infty
\neq
0
=
\mu\bigg(\bigcap_n A_n\bigg),
\end{equation*}
i.e., $\mu$ is not continuous from above.

The measure $\mu$ is (of course) $\sigma$-additive,
and one can show that this already implies continuity from below.

Once I tried to weaken conditions to a situation that would apply to both nonnegative, signed and complex measures.
One relaxed condition that I believe would do the trick was that
\begin{equation*}
x + \mu(A) = y + \mu(A)\quad\Rightarrow\quad x = y 
\end{equation*}
for any $x$ and $y$ and any measurable set $A$.

Comment: My bad, I must've mentioned that we follow the following definition of the continuity from above: $\mu$ is called continuous from above at $A$ iff for any sequence $A_i\downarrow A$ *with some $\mu(A_i) < +\infty$*, we have that $\mu(A) = \lim_i \mu(A_i)$. I unfortunately assumed that this was standard. I will put that in my original post.

Comment: Then according to our definition, your example doesn't show that $\mu$ is continuous from above at $\emptyset$ for each $\mu(A_n) = +\infty$.

Comment: No, actually my bad: your definition where $\mu(A_i) < +\infty$ for some $A_i$ is the only one I know but I overlooked this part, sorry. And so mine indeed is not a counter example. Interesting question though.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: Do you think writing $\sigma$-finite $\mu$ as an infinite sum of finite $\mu_n$ could work? There are measurable $X_n\subset X$ such that $X = \bigcup_n X_n$ and $\mu(X_n) < \infty$ for each $n$. Define $\mu_n(A) = \mu(A\cap X_n)$. If $\mu$ is continuous from above then so is each $\mu_n$, hence each $\mu_n$ is continuous from below, and then $\lim_i\mu(A) = \lim_i\sum_n\mu_n(A_i) = \sum_n\lim_i\mu_n(A_i) = \sum_n\mu_n(A) = \mu(A)$ where I believe swapping the limit and infinite sum is allowed.

Comment: That's genius! Now I only need to think about why we can interchange limits here.